# ¿Es correcto el uso del close tag (cerrar todas las etiquetas) en HTML?

Tags: html, html5, buenas-prácticas

Es una duda que tengo desde hace tiempo. Soy estudiante de Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Web, y por lo menos ahí cerramos las etiquetas de los elementos `HTML`. Ejemplos:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

ó

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Otros casos:

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="img">
```

ó

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="img" />
```

Así con muchas otras como `<br>`, `<input>`, ...

He buscado en internet, y la mayor parte de respuestas que encuentro son meras *opiniones*.
Ejemplos de links:

- [CodeAcademy question](https://www.codecademy.com/es/forum_questions/4fedcb1b6a5e31000302412a)
- [Treehouse post](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/to-close-or-not-to-close-tags-in-html5)
- [StackOverflow (otra pregunta)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860492/how-to-close-img-tag-properly)

> Además de opiniones a la hora de visualizar el HTML, también he encontrado que 
>     podría tener relación con las diferencias entre `HTML5` y `HTML/XML`, pero 
>     nunca he llegado a obtener algo concreto. Del mismo modo he leído que puede influir a 
>     la hora de *debugear* el código, pero otra vez, nada concreto.

### Importante

No quiero buscar opiniones, principalmente porque este sitio no es para ello. Si no hay ninguna razón técnica por la cual se utiliza una forma u otra, no necesitaría saber más.

Comment: Si haces uso de frameworks como Spring es necesario cerrarlas ya que en caso contrario al arrancar la aplicacion te arrojara un error y no podras iniciarla.

Comment: De momento no he utilizado, al menos en profundidad, frameworks de JS u otros lenguajes. De cara a su futuro uso, ¿qué sería lo mas recomendable respecto a su uso en _frameworks_?

Comment: Spring es un framework de Java. Y pues, debes cerrar las etiquetas si o si. Desconozco ya que aun no he probado si esto se debe al motor de plantilla. Yo uso thymeleaf y es obligatorio el cierre de todas y cada una de las etiquetas. Saludos.

Answer (score 13):

## Respuesta corta

HTML es el "estándar para la creación de páginas web". Este es flexible en cuando al cierre de las etiquetas, pero hay algunas variantes de este que no lo son como XHTML, que pueden tener otros requisitos que no están en HTML 4 / 5

Desde el punto de vista técnico lo que marca si se debe o no cerrar una etiqueta es el estándar que quieras cumplir y los requisitos de herramientas y librerías que utilices.

## Respuesta extendida

En relación a los  casos mencionados en la pregunta como ejemplo `<meta>` y `<img>`, de acuerdo a [HTML 5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#void-elements) ambas son etiquetas vacías por lo que se "recomienda" que no se cierren.

NOTA: HTML 5.2 es una recomendación, no una especificación.

La cita textual es la siguiente:

> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements.

En el [XHTML™ 1.0 The Extensible HyperText Markup Language (Second Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) de la W3C se incluye una sección de diferencias con respecto a HTML 4 en el que "lo primero" que señala es que en XHTML ciertas prácticas deben cambiar.

> 4. Differences with HTML 4 This section is informative.
>
> Due to the fact that XHTML is an XML application, certain practices
>   that were perfectly legal in SGML-based HTML 4 [HTML4] must be
>   changed.

Luego una líneas más adelante habla acerca de que que se requieren etiquetas de cierre para los elementos que no son vacíos. Incluye ejemplos de correcto / incorrecto usando para tal efecto la etiqueta `<p>`.

> 4.3. For non-empty elements, end tags are required
>
> In SGML-based HTML 4 certain elements were permitted to omit the end
>   tag; with the elements that followed implying closure. XML does not
>   allow end tags to be omitted. All elements other than those declared
>   in the DTD as EMPTY must have an end tag. Elements that are declared
>   in the DTD as EMPTY can have an end tag or can use empty element
>   shorthand (see Empty Elements).
>
> CORRECT: terminated elements
>
> ```
> <p>here is a paragraph.</p><p>here is another paragraph.</p>
> ```
>
> INCORRECT: unterminated elements
>
> ```
> <p>here is a paragraph.<p>here is another paragraph.
> ```

Comment: Creo que es la mejor respuesta, ya que es la única que responde correctamente, respetando lo que dice W3C.

Comment: @Rubén sería una mejora en tu respuesta si las citas tengan su símil en español.

Comment: @Davlio De hecho sería bueno que la W3C publicara en español.

Comment: Las traducciones son importantes y aquí tu respuesta podría prestarse a confusión. Traducimos: *Los elementos vacíos solo tienen una etiqueta de inicio; **no se deben especificar etiquetas finales para elementos vacíos.*** A leerlo se podría creer que W3C desaconseja usar algo como `<br />`, cuando lo que desaconseja es: `<br></br>`. Esto: `<br />`, **no es una etiqueta final**, es una etiqueta de cierre si le podemos llamar así, según el marcado XML y totalmente válido. No es desaconsejado en ninguna parte. Una etiqueta de cierre es [otra cosa](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#end-tags)

Answer (score 6):

La razon por la que algunos elementos no requieren cierre es porque son [void Elements o elementos vacios](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#void-elements). Estos elmentos no soportan ningún contenido dentro de ellos.

Segun la documentacion [HTML 5.3 (Draft), sección 8.1.2, párrafo 3](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#void-elements) de la W3C dice:

> Los elementos void no pueden tener ningún contenido (ya que no hay una
>   etiqueta de cierre, no se puede poner contenido entre la etiqueta de
>   inicio y la etiqueta de cierre).

Los elementos son void son:

```
<area>, <base>, <br>, <col>, <embed>, <hr>, <img>, <input>, <link>, <meta>, <param>, <source>, <track>, <wbr>
```

La lista de elementos que requieren cierre son los siguientes:

1. [Elementos de plantilla](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-scripting.html#elementdef-template)
2. Elementos de texto puro: `<script>`, `<style>`
3. Elementos de texto escapado: `<textarea>`, `<title>`
4. Foreign elements: Elementos del espacio de nombres MathML y el espacio de nombres SVG.
5. Elementos normales: Todos los demás elementos HTML permitidos son elementos normales.

Answer (score 6):

La respuesta a tu pregunta no es tan sencilla como podría parecer, ya que intervienen varios elementos y todo dependerá del escenario, o sea, del uso que le darás a tu documento y de cómo vas a declararlo.

Para ser objetivos.

## 1. Aclarando lo que es el *cierre de etiquetas*

Podemos decir en primer lugar que **una cosa es el cierre de etiquetas y otra cosa es un elemento que termina con `/>`**.

Una etiqueta de cierre es definida del siguiente modo en el [apartado de 8.1.2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#end-tags):

Las etiquetas de finalización deben tener el siguiente formato:

1. El primer carácter de una etiqueta final debe ser un carácter U + 003C U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN (<).
2. El segundo carácter de una etiqueta final debe ser un carácter SOLIDUS U+002F (/).
3. Los siguientes caracteres de una etiqueta final deben ser el nombre de   etiqueta del elemento.
4. Después del nombre de la etiqueta, puede haber uno o más caracteres espaciales.
5. Por último, las etiquetas de cierre deben cerrarse con un carácter U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN (>).

De lo dicho en esos cinco puntos podemos deducir con toda claridad que cuando usamos `<br />, <hr />...`, **no estamos cerrando etiquetas**, sino que lo que estamos haciendo es que **el mismo elemento de apertura termine con `/>`**. Esto lo veremos con más claridad en el punto 2, cuando citemos el apartado 4.6 de la W3C Recommendation...

## 2.La norma establecida para XML/HTML

En el [apartado 4.6 de la *W3C Recommendation*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6) existe una norma que habla sobre los elementos vacíos:

> ### 4.6. Empty Elements
>
> Empty elements must either have an end tag or the start tag must end
>   with `/>`. For instance, `<br/>` or `<hr></hr>`. See [HTML
>   Compatibility Guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines) for information on ways to ensure this is
>   backward compatible with HTML 4 user agents.
>
> ---
>
> ### 4.6. Elementos vacíos
>
> Los elementos vacíos deben tener una etiqueta final o la etiqueta de
>   inicio debe finalizar con `/>`. Por ejemplo, `<br/>` o `<hr> </ hr>`. Consulte [Pautas de compatibilidad de HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines) para obtener
>   información sobre cómo asegurarse de que sea compatible con versiones
>   anteriores de los agentes de usuario de HTML 4.

Para esta norma, un cierre de etiqueta sería hacer esto: `</hr>`, lo cual sí está permitido en XML. Sin embargo, la norma dice claramente que esto no es un cierre de etiqueta: `<hr />`, sino **una etiqueta de inicio que finaliza con `/`.**

## 3. ¿Hay una norma definida en HTML?

**(a)**. En HTML hay normas definidas **para el cierre de etiquetas propiamente dicho** (entendiendo la diferencia explicada en el punto 1). E incluso hay normas para etiquetas que se pueden omitir.

**(b)**. En cuanto a **etiquetas de apertura que terminen así `/>` no hay ninguna prohibición**, como podría mal interpretarse.

### (a). Etiquetas que se pueden omitir en HTML

HTML permite omitir ciertas etiquetas **tanto de apertura como de cierre** en contextos bien especificados en el apartado **[apartado 8.1.2.4. Optional tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#optional-tags)** de *W3C Recommendation*.

Allí se dice de entrada lo siguiente:

**Ciertas etiquetas pueden omitirse**.

Sí, ¡hasta la etiqueta `<html>` puede omitirse en algunos casos (lo puedes ver en el enlace).

Luego, da una explicación detallada de **cuáles etiquetas** pueden omitirse y por qué.

A continuación, las **etiquetas de cierre que pueden omitirse en HTML** (nótese que no se hace mención de esto `<elemento />` en ninguna parte):

- `</html>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `<html>` no es seguido inmediatamente por un comentario.
- `</head>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `<head>` no es seguido inmediatamente por un espacio o un comentario.
- `</body>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `<body>` no es seguido inmediatamente por un comentario.
- `</li>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `<li>` es seguido inmediatamente por otro elemento `<li>` o si no hay más contenido en el elemento padre.
- `</dt>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `<dt>` va seguido inmediatamente por otro elemento `<dt>` o un elemento `<dd>`.
- `</dd>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `<dd>` es seguido inmediatamente por otro elemento `<dd>` o un elemento `<dt>`, o si no hay más contenido en el elemento padre.
- `</p>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `<p>` es seguido inmediatamente por un elemento  `address`, `article`, `aside`, `blockquote`, `details`, `div`, `dl`, `fieldset`, `figcaption`, `figure`, `footer`, `form`, `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `header`, `hr`, `main`, `nav`, `ol`, `p`, `pre`, `section`, `table`, o `ul, o si no hay más contenido en el elemento primario y el elemento principal es un elemento HTML que no es elemento`a`,`audio`,`del`,`ins`,`map`,`noscript`, o`video` o un [elemento personalizado autónomo](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#autonomous-custom-element).
- `</rt>`: puede omitirse si al elemento `rt` le sigue inmediatamente un elemento `rt` o `rp`, o si no hay más contenido en el elemento padre.
- `</rp>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `rp` es seguido inmediatamente por un elemento `rt` o `rp`, o si no hay más contenido en el elemento padre.
- `</optgroup>`: se puede omitir si el elemento de `optgroup` es seguido inmediatamente por otro elemento `optgroup` o si no hay más contenido en el elemento principal.
- `</option>`: puede omitirse si el elemento de `option` es seguido inmediatamente por otro elemento de `option`, o si lo sigue inmediatamente un elemento  `optgroup`, o si no hay más contenido en el elemento principal.
- `: puede omitirse si al elemento`colgroup` no le sigue inmediatamente un carácter de espacio o un comentario.
- `</caption>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `caption` no es seguido inmediatamente por un carácter de espacio o un comentario.
- `</thead>`: se puede omitir si el elemento `thead` es seguido inmediatamente por un elemento `tbody` o `tfoot`.
- `</tbody>`: se puede omitir si el elemento `tbody` es seguido inmediatamente por un elemento `tbody` o `tfoot`, o si no hay más contenido en el elemento principal.
- `</tfoot>`: puede omitirse si no hay más contenido en el elemento padre.
- `</tr>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `tr` es seguido inmediatamente por otro elemento `tr`, o si no hay más contenido en el elemento padre.
- `</td>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `td` es seguido inmediatamente por un elemento `td` o `th`, o si no hay más contenido en el elemento padre.
- `</th>`: puede omitirse si el elemento `th` es seguido inmediatamente por un elemento `td` o `th`, o si no hay más contenido en el elemento principal.

### (b). No se prohíbe en ninguna parte que la *apertura* de las etiquetas vacías terminenasí `/>`

En el apartado **[8.1.2. Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements)** de W3C Recommendation se dice lo siguiente sobre las etiquetas:

> **Tags**
>
> Se utilizan para delimitar el inicio y el final de los elementos en el
>   marcado.  Raw text, escapable raw text y los elementos normales tienen
>   una etiqueta de inicio para indicar dónde comienzan y una etiqueta de
>   finalización para indicar dónde terminan.
>
> Las etiquetas de inicio y fin de ciertos elementos normales se pueden
>   omitir, como se describe a continuación en la sección de [etiquetas
>   opcionales](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#optional-tags). Aquellos que no pueden ser omitidos no deben ser
>   omitidos.
>
> Los [elementos vacíos](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#void-elements) solo tienen una etiqueta de inicio; no se
>   deben especificar etiquetas finales para elementos vacíos<sup>1</sup>.
>   Los [elementos externos](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#foreign-elements) deben tener una etiqueta de inicio y una
>   etiqueta de finalización o una etiqueta de inicio marcada como de
>   cierre automático, en cuyo caso no deben tener una etiqueta de cierre.

Cuando el apartado **8.1.2** dice: ***no se deben especificar etiquetas finales para elementos vacíos*** se refiere a que no se debe cerrar un elemento vacío de este modo <s>`<br></br>`</s>. O sea, **esto no es una etiqueta final: `<br />`**, sino que es la misma etiqueta de apertura terminando en `/>`, como ya hemos demostrado más arriba.

---

## 4. En resumen

Aclarados los conceptos. La pregunta sigue siendo si conviene terminar nuestros elementos vacíos de este modo `/>`.

- Si tu documento tiene que pasar una validación del tipo XML/XHTML, porque depende de algún framework, o porque en un futuro piensas migrar tu código a XML o por otros motivos similares, entonces está claro que deberás terminar tus elementos vacíos cumpliendo la normativa requerida por XML/XHTML.
- Si tu documento no tiene que pasar ninguna validación, sino ser renderizado por el navegador. Puedes aplicar las normas de XML sin problemas o no aplicarlas... Aún en el caso de que indiques que es un documento que debería observar las normas de XML, los navegadores modernos no te darán ningún error. [Según lo afirmado en el blog de WebKit](https://webkit.org/blog/68/understanding-html-xml-and-xhtml/), actualmente casi todas las páginas que supuestamente deberían ser XHML, son renderizadas como páginas del tipo `text/html`. Eso quiere decir que cualquiera de las dos formas es válida.

---

### El problema de la compatibilidad

En este caso, como en muchos, chocamos con el problema de la compatibilidad, el cual como sabemos es difícil debido a la evolución de los navegadores y a formas diferentes de comportamiento entre ellos en situaciones particulares.

Como ejemplo ilustrativo, podemos ver el caso particular de las etiquetas `<script>` y `<canvas>`, tratado en el [blog de WebKit](https://webkit.org/blog/68/understanding-html-xml-and-xhtml/).

Esto es lo que dice:

> #### Acerca de esas etiquetas `<script>` y `<canvas>`
>
> Prometí al principio de esta publicación que les cuente todo lo que tenía que ver
>   con el cierre de scripts y etiquetas de canvas en los widgets de
>   escritorio. Bueno, el resultado es que la sintaxis de autocierre de
>   estilo XML en HTML no siempre es tan inocuo.
>
> La versión 2.0 de WebKit Safari tenía una peculiaridad especial para
>   tratar los elementos de script con la sintaxis de cierre automático
>   (como esta: `<script src = "myscript.js" />`) como si realmente
>   estuvieran cerrados correctamente. En ese momento, los navegadores
>   basados ​​en Gecko como Firefox tenían un capricho similar, y
>   decidimos copiarlo para compatibilidad con sitios web particulares.
>   Sin embargo, las versiones futuras de Firefox eliminarán esta
>   peculiaridad, y este tipo de comportamiento quedará explícitamente
>   prohibido por estándares futuros basados ​​en HTML, como Web Apps 1.0.
>   Por lo tanto, probablemente eliminaremos esta peculiaridad en futuras
>   versiones de WebKit también. Desafortunadamente, código HTML basado en
>   esta peculiaridad de análisis se ha deslizado en muchos widgets de
>   escritorio. Un WebKit que no admite esta peculiaridad daría lugar a
>   widgets rotos: el código de script externo nunca se ejecutará.
>
> Hay un problema similar con los elementos `<canvas>`, ya que se abre
>   paso a través del proceso de estandarización. `<canvas>` se implementó
>   originalmente en Safari como una etiqueta vacía como `img`, pero los
>   estándares y otros navegadores han desaparecido, por lo que requieren
>   una etiqueta de cierre explícita para admitir el contenido
>   alternativo. Los widgets tocan dos peligros diferentes aquí: muchos
>   utilizan la sintaxis de cierre automático XML (`<canvas />`), mientras
>   que otros tienen una etiqueta antigua sin cerrar (`<canvas>`). De
>   cualquier manera, debe cambiar a usar una etiqueta de cierre explícita
>   (`<canvas> </ canvas>`, o las futuras versiones de WebKit pensarán que
>   el resto de su documento está dentro del elemento canvas y no lo
>   renderizarán.

---

<sup>1</sup> La afirmación: ***no se deben especificar etiquetas finales para elementos vacíos*** podría prestarse a **confusión**. Aquí no se prohíben usos como estos: `<br />, <hr />`, etc. los cuales son totalmente válidos. Lo que se prohibe es esto: <s>`<br></br>`</s>. Ya que una [**etiqueta final**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#end-tags) está definida como `</elemento>`. En cambio, cuando usamos `<br />`usamos la sintaxis de cierre XML. Es preciso no confundirse en este punto y concluir **erróneamente** que se está prohibiendo cerrar adecuadamente los elementos vacíos con la sintaxis XML.

Answer (score 3):

> El tema es que ya sé que no hay que cerrar las etiquetas necesariamente, lo que realmente busco es saber si hay razones más sólidas para determinarlo

Este comentario lo has dejado en una de las respuestas que te han dado a tu pregunta. Te comento que si existen razones sólidas para el cierre de las etiquetas HTML.

El correcto cierre de las etiquetas **HTML** es imprescindible para poder ejecutar o incluir **librerías de terceros** (aquellas no creadas por tí pero que deseas utilizar en tus proyectos de desarrollo) debido a que en su gran mayoría estas librerias siguen los **estándares** mundiales de desarrollo web.

Por ejemplo **HTML2PDF** es una clase **PHP** que se implementa para generar reportes en **PDF** exige el correcto cierre de las etiquetas **HTML** para poder funcionar. Cualquier omisión de cierre de etiquetas (principalmente en las manejadas para generar tablas) arrojará un error en el proceso de creación del **PDF** evitando que el mismo sea generado correctamente.De la misma manera pasa con muchos frameworks utilizados actualmente.

> ¿Es correcto el uso del close tag (cerrar todas las etiquetas) en HTML?

**En conclusión** el hecho de que las etiquetas **HTML** de manera estándar puedan interpretarse "correctamente" sin cerrarlas como es debido no quiere decir que sea una buena práctica. Lo correcto es el cierre como es debido de cada etiqueta **HTML** para garantizar la "portabilidad" y "reusabilidad" de tu código además de permitirte utilizar sin problemas librerías desarrolladas por terceros.

Espero te sea de utilidad, Un Saludo!

Comment: Por lo que he entendido gracias a esta respuesta y a las demás, es importante a la hora de incorporar librerías y/o frameworks. De momento es el resultado que buscaba.

Comment: Me alegra que te ha sido de utilidad mi respuesta @MigherdCa

Answer (score 0):

Si vemos un ejemplo de la W3C , quien fija los estándares, podemos apreciar que no necesariamente cierran las etiquetas.

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">

<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: W3school o W3C?

Comment: El tema es que ya sé que no hay que cerrar las etiquetas _necesariamente_, lo que **realmente** busco es saber si hay razones más sólidas para determinarlo.

Comment: Además, que aparezca un ejemplo (o incluso muchos, o todos) no indica el por qué de esto, ni especifica que ese sea el estándar. Viendo un ejemplo, no estamos explicando nada, y creo que se acercaría más a una opinión, que el autor de la pregunta específicamente pidió que no quería. Es decir, si está esto especificado en el estándar, ¿en qué sección? ¿podrías citar la fuente por explícito? ¿qué implicancias tiene? ¿en qué tipo de documentos?