# Notice: Undefined index: Val

Tags: php, html, undefined

Tengo este problema:

```
Notice: Undefined index: N1.
```

Estoy utlizando **HTML** incrustado con **PHP**. Este es mi código:

```php
form name="F2" method="post">
    Ingrese número
    <input type="number" name="Val">
    <input type="submit" name="BtnCalcular" value="Calcular">
</form>

<?php
$Valor=$_POST["Val"];
if ($Valor % 6 == 0) {
    echo "Es múltiplo";
} else {
    echo "No es múltiplo";
}
?>
```

Comment: Saludos. Hace falta el fragmento del código donde ocurre el error; básicamente te indica que (por lo visto) de un array (sea o no asociativo) el elemento que se quiere acceder no existe.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Deberías de intentar mejorar la pregunta, para que no se reporte como de baja calidad, y termine cerrada. Puede ayudarte realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: A tu formulario le falta la etiqueta de apertura: `<`, debería ser `<form name="F2" method="post">`. Corregido eso, como depuración pon un `var_dump($_POST);` para verificar lo que se está recibiendo. Ten en cuenta que el ´input` debe recibir un valor, de lo contrario no se enviará con el formulario.

Comment: Hola A. Cedana, podrias escribirlo en codigo, soy muy nueva en el mundo de al programacion, te lo agradezco

Answer (score 2):

En tu código hay un problema de etiqueta, pues **a tu elemento `form` le falta la etiqueta de apertura `<`**.

En HTML los elementos tienen generalmente etiquetas de apertura `<` y de cierre  `>`. Si las etiquetas no se escriben correctamente los elementos no se reconocerán como tal, produciendo un HTML inválido. De modo que en este caso no se está reconociendo el formulario al no estar etiquetado correctamente.

Así debería funcionar:

```php
<form name="F2" method="post"> 
    Ingrese número <input type="number" name="Val" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="BtnCalcular" value="Calcular" /> 
</form> 

<?php 
    $Valor=$_POST["Val"]; 
    if ($Valor % 6 == 0) { 
        echo "Es múltiplo"; 
    } else { 
        echo "No es múltiplo"; 
    } 
?>
```

Finalmente, recomendaría que **acostumbres a cerrar los elementos cuando ello sea requerido** (como el caso de los elementos `input`). Aunque HTML es permisivo con el cierre de ciertos elementos, si en un futuro hace falta migrar ese contenido a XML por ejemplo tus `input` sin cerrar no pasarían una validación XML. Este tema ha sido tratado con mucho detalle en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/136203/29967). Allí puedes ver también otras respuestas con argumentos a favor del cierre de los elementos, como el uso de ciertas bibliotecas de terceros, que no funcionarían si no tienes un HTML escrito con rigor.

Comment: aun sigue el error

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un `var_dump($_POST);` y decirnos que muestra, @SilviaMolina?

Comment: Otra cosa: faltaba cerrar tus `input`, corrige también eso agregando `/` en los dos, como aparece en el código editado.

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de la respuesta que te falta la etiqueta de apertura `<` de tu formulario.

El error `Notice: Undefined index: Val` es porque en algunos casos la variable `$Valor = $_POST["Val"];` no está definida, es decir, no tiene valor alguna.

> Para evitar dicho error seria conveniente un par de reglas:

1. resetear tus variables al inicio de tu código, algo como `$Valor = null;`.
2. Luego antes de obtener la variable $valor o mejor dicho trabajar con `$_POST`, comprobaría que el botón
   de tu formulario está definida mediante la función `isset`, es decir, `if (isset($_POST['BtnCalcular'])) {  //Obtener datos formulario    }`.
3. También debes comprobar que tenga algún valor tu `input`, es decir,
   `if (empty($_POST["Val"]) { }` antes de crear la variable $Valor, si no en algún caso podrá estar vacío y generarte el error.

Por último también añadiría el atributo `action` a tu formulario.
`action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"`

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```
<form name="F2" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
    Ingrese un número <input type="number" name="Val" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="BtnCalcular" value="Calcular" /> 
</form> 

<?php 
//Resetear
$Valor = null;

// Comprobar que esta definida tu formulario
if (isset($_POST['BtnCalcular'])) {      
    // Comprobar que el input tengo algun valor y sea un valor entero.
    if (empty($_POST["Val"]) && is_int($_POST['Val'])) { 
        echo 'debes rellenar un valor valido';  
    // Mi input tiene valor  
    } else {
        // Obtienes el valor de tu input
        $Valor = $_POST["Val"] ?: ''; 
        
        // Salida de respuesta segun tu comprobación (if)
        if ($Valor % 6 == 0) { 
            echo "Es múltiplo"; 
        } else { 
            echo "No es múltiplo"; 
        }       
    }

}
?>
```