# Por que salen los errores de indice no definido al enviar el formulario de contacto desde mi pagina web?

Tags: php

**Me salen mensajes como este al hacer el envío.**
Notice: Undefined index: nombre in /storage/ssd2/518/16259518/public_html/Contacto/enviar.php on line 2

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd2/518/16259518/public_html/Contacto/enviar.php:2) in /storage/ssd2/518/16259518/public_html/Contacto/enviar.php on line 23

---

```html
<form class="formulario" action="enviarContacto.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" REQUIRED name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value=''>
  <input type="text" REQUIRED name="correo" placeholder="Correo"  value=''>
  <input type="tel" REQUIRED name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" value=''>
  <textarea  rows="7" cols="30" REQUIRED name="mensaje" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje aquí"> </textarea><br>
  <button class="LoginButton" onclick="submit" value=''>Enviar</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Deberías mostrar al menos un poco de código de lo que has hecho y el error que te dio.

Comment: Te dejo un enlace de **SOes** que te podría quizás ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/408958/notice-undefined-index-val

Comment: debberias mostrar enviar.php, que es donde salen los errores

Comment: <?php

$destino= "XXXXX@gmail.com";

$nombre= $_POST["nombre"];
$correo= $_POST["correo"];
$telefono= $_POST["telefono"];
$mensaje= $_POST["mensaje"];

$contenido = "Nombre: ". $nombre . "\nCorreo: ". $correo . "\nTelefono: ". $telefono . "\nMensaje: ". $mensaje;

mail($destino, "Contacto", $contenido);
header("Location:index.php");
      
?>

Comment: ¿Porque en tu `action` se llama `enviarContacto.php` y en cambio en tu mensaje de error es `enviar.php` ? Quizás tu fallo esta allí, porque las variables están correctamente creadas por `$_POST`, aun así añadiría `if (isset($_POST)) { //creo mis variables }` y si resteas tus variables al principio mucho mejor aún, algo como `$nombre = $correo = $etc = NULL;`