# Salto lineal en array con php

Tags: php, array

Tengo este array que me funciona a la perfección pero me separa la lista con una "," y no hace salto de línea que es lo que no se como implementarlo aquí:

```
if (is_array($_POST['check_lista'])) {
    $selected = '';
    $num_servicio = count($_POST['check_lista']);
    $current = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['check_lista'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($current != $num_servicio-1)
            $selected .= $value.',';
        else
            $selected .= $value.'.';
        $current++;
    }
}
```

Ahora lo muestra así:

> servicio1, servicio2, servicio3.

y lo necesito así:

> servicio1,
> servicio2,
> servicio3.

He probado con **`\n`**, **`\r\n`** y muchas cosas pero no me ha funcionado.

Un saludo.

Comment: En PHP puedes usar `PHP_EOL`, que te agregará un salto de línea independientemente del sistema operativo. Por ejemplo: **`$selected .= "$value,".PHP_EOL;`**

Comment: Si va a ir dentro de código HTML debes incluir el tag `<br>` o colocar cada linea en un elemento de bloque tipo `div` o `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En PHP puedes usar la [constante predefinida `PHP_EOL`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php), que te agregará un salto de línea independientemente del sistema operativo.

Al menos en mi caso, `PHP_EOL` sirve también dentro de un contexto HTML, por lo que debería funcionar como salto de línea.

Por otra parte, y gracias al comentario de @Triby logré entender la duda del `if` sin sentido en la pregunta.

Con `implode()` puedes tener los datos así:

```
servicio1,
servicio2,
servicio3.
```

Haciendo simplemente esto:

```
if (is_array($_POST['check_lista'])) {
    $selected = implode(','.PHP_EOL,$_POST['check_lista']).".";
}
```

Sí, sí, no hace falta nada más.

Si `PHP_EOL` no funciona en tu contexto, lo puedes cambiar por `<br />`:

```
if (is_array($_POST['check_lista'])) {
    $selected = implode(',<br />',$_POST['check_lista']).".";
}
```

**Eso es todo lo que tienes que escribir, sin bucle ni nada.**

O, si prefieres un ternario:

```
$selected = (is_array($_POST['check_lista'])) ?
    implode(',<br />',$_POST['check_lista'])."."
    : 'Valor por defecto si no es array' ;
```

---

`@deprecated`

Puedes también simplificar tu código con un *operador ternario*. Aunque el `if ... else` no tiene mucho sentido, porque hace lo mismo en ambos bloques.

Esto:

```
    if ($current != $num_servicio-1)
        $selected .= $value.',';
    else
        $selected .= $value.'.';
```

Es lo mismo que esto:

```
        $selected .= $value.'.';
```

Por lo que no sé para que es el  `if` en tu código.

Imaginemos que tenga que agregarse algo distinto:

```
if (is_array($_POST['check_lista'])) {
    $selected = '';
    $num_servicio = count($_POST['check_lista']);
    $current = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['check_lista'] as $key => $value) {
        $selected .= ($current != $num_servicio-1)
            $selected .= "$value,".PHP_EOL;
        else
            $selected .= "$value y OTRA cosa".PHP_EOL;
        $current++;
    }
}
```

Con un ternario simplificas así:

```
if (is_array($_POST['check_lista'])) {
    $selected = '';
    $num_servicio = count($_POST['check_lista']);
    $current = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['check_lista'] as $key => $value) {
        $selected .= ($current != $num_servicio-1)
            ? "$value,".PHP_EOL; : "$value y OTRA cosa".PHP_EOL;
        $current++;
    }
}
```

De todos modos intuyo que todo el proceso que intentas ahí podría simplificarse, verificando quizá con `in_array()` o de otro modo (el contexto no es explicado claramente por lo que no podría ser más preciso en mi afirmación). Sea como sea, tu problema aquí es el salto de línea, pero señalo también esto porque me parece que mareas demasiado los datos y quizá convendría optimizar.

Comment: @Triby gracias por señalar el error, ahora corrijo. A veces es bueno tener varias posibilidades. De todos modos no queda claro lo que se intenta hacer en el `if`.

Comment: Ese `if` es solo para agregar comas entre cada elemento, excepto el último, que lleva punto.

Comment: ¡Madre mía, ya decía yo que algo raro había! Entonces con esto basta @Triby: **`echo implode(','.PHP_EOL,$_POST['check_lista']).".";`**, no hace falta nada más.

Comment: Es correcto, excepto que el salto de línea no se representa como tal en el navegador y creo que esa es la parte más importante de la pregunta.

Comment: @Triby buen apunte. ¿Sabes exactamente por qué etiqueta HTML es cambiado `PHP_EOL` o ese dependería de cada contexto?

Comment: `PHP_EOL` depende del sistema operativo, pero para el navegador basta con `<br>`, sin importar que tenga o no `\n`, `\r` o combinación de ambas.

Comment: al final con `if (is_array($_POST['check_lista'])) {
    $selected = implode(','.PHP_EOL,$_POST['check_lista']).".";
}` me funciona perfectamente gracias y saludos

Comment: con el if lo que se hacia era poner la coma para separar la lista y el punto al final de la lista gracias por ayudarme a solucionarlo

Comment: Mucho mejor ahora. Solo por que soy muy quisquilloso, en HTML5 ya no es necesario terminar con `/>` las etiquetas de autocierr, se recomienda simplemente `<br>`. +1

Comment: @Triby yo siempre cierro los elementos, más que nada por salvar la compatibilidad con XML/XHTML ([Aquí he hablado ampliamente sobre esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/136203/29967)). Nunca se sabe... en caso de necesitar migrar el contenido a `XML/XHTML` los elementos void no cerrados (`<br>, <hr>`, etc) darán error en la validación.

Comment: Por eso decía _"se recomienda"_, pero tu argumento es completamente válido y mi [Monk interno](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monk) deberá asimilarlo. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que tu salida es a una pagina HTML los caracteres de control `\n` y `\r` no tienen efecto.

Debes usar los tags apropiados.

- `br` coloca un salto de linea en un bloque.
- Tags de bloque como `div` y `p` obligan tambien a un salto de linea entre ellos.

Tu código quedaría así usando el tag `br`:

```
if (is_array($_POST['check_lista'])) {
    $selected = '';
    $num_servicio = count($_POST['check_lista']);
    $current = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['check_lista'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($current != $num_servicio-1)
            $selected .= $value.',<br>';
        else
            $selected .= $value.'.<br>';
        $current++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero no es necesario el ciclo, se puede hacer con [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php): `$selected = implode(',<br>', $_POST['check_lista']);`

Comment: Correcto. Y allí faltaría la concatenación final con `.<br>`

Comment: Creo que solo sería el punto final, pero sí, falta esa parte en la sugerencia.